# Why and how to run system process from /etc/rc.local?

Tags: c, linux, qt, process, system

I am not able to run some processes from /etc/rc.local. From the prompt the applications or command lines works. I've made a simple application in c, based on the other post and the process is not executed. What am I doing wrong?

Other process like "insmod /home/root/ov5640.ko" also works only when executed from command line or from an application who was executed from the prompt, but not directly from the /etc/rc.local, witch returns  insmod as an unrecognized command.

Thanks for any help.

```
// can_init.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

    int status;

    // By calling fork(), a child process will be created as a exact duplicate of the calling process.
    // Search for fork() (maybe "man fork" on Linux) for more information.
    if(fork() == 0){ 
        // Child process will return 0 from fork()
        printf("I'm the child process.\n");
        
    status = system("ifconfig can0 down");
    status = system("ip link set can0 type can tq 400 prop-seg 3 phase-seg1 8 phase-seg2 8 sjw 4");
    status = system("ip link set can0 type can restart-ms 100");
    status = system("ifconfig can0 up");
    status = system("ip -details -statistics link show can0");

        exit(0);
    }else{
        // Parent process will return a non-zero value from fork()
        printf("I'm the parent.\n");
    }

    printf("This is my main program and it will continue running and doing anything i want to...\n");

    return 0;
}





  /etc/rc.local

#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.


echo 30000 >  /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes
echo "0" > /sys/class/graphics/fb0/blank
/home/root/can_init >/dev/null 2>&1 &
echo "test 2"
exit 0
```

Comment: What's the output of
`ls -l /etc/rc.local` ? 
Has it been made executable?

Comment: `ifconfig` and `ip` are in `/usr/sbin` (e.g.). But, that directory _may_ not be in `$PATH` when invoked from `/etc/rc.local`. You can add the full path to these commands in your C program. Or, you can add (e.g.): `export PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH` to your RC file.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

root@ATK-IMX6U:~# ls -l /etc/rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 tracing 497 Mar 18 17:05 /etc/rc.local

Comment: Thank for the hint. Not sure if is that what you mean. 

#!/bin/sh -e

export PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH
/home/root/can_init >/dev/null 2>&1 &
echo "test 2"
exit 0

env
...
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
...


But still not working.

Comment: Craig Estey, it worked! : )   Thank you very much!  I did not find ifconfig in the /usr/sbin folder so searching it I saw that it is actually in the /sbin folder:  export PATH = /sbin: $PATH      . And worked for insmod too.

Comment: Rather than editing the post title to mark the question solved, can you briefly write up the solution in an answer posted to this question? It will be more helpful to future readers as compared to comments which may be ephemeral.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,

As Craig Estey said, by including the /sbin path to the /etc/rc.local the application succed to execute the ifconfig, ip and ismod commands

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.


echo 30000 >  /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes
echo "0" > /sys/class/graphics/fb0/blank
source /etc/profile
export PATH=/sbin:$PATH
/home/root/can_init >/dev/null 2>&1 &
echo "test 2"
exit 0
```

```
/* from can_init.c */ 

status = system("/usr/sbin/ifconfig can0 down");
    status = system("ip link set can0 type can tq 400 prop-seg 3 phase-seg1 8 phase-seg2 8 sjw 4");
    status = system("ip link set can0 type can restart-ms 100");
    status = system("ifconfig can0 up");
    status = system("ip -details -statistics link show can0");

    status = system("insmod /home/root/mx6s_capture.ko");
```

After reboot, the application executed the can configuration:

```
Running local boot scripts (/etc/rc.local)test 2
.
[    9.635097] flexcan 2090000.can can0: writing ctrl=0x0bff2002

[   13.566306] CSI: Registered sensor subdevice: ov5640 1-0021
^C
root@ATK-IMX6U:~# ip -details link show can0
2: can0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10
    link/can  promiscuity 0
    can state ERROR-ACTIVE (berr-counter tx 0 rx 0) restart-ms 100
          bitrate 125000 sample-point 0.600
          tq 400 prop-seg 3 phase-seg1 8 phase-seg2 8 sjw 4
          flexcan: tseg1 4..16 tseg2 2..8 sjw 1..4 brp 1..256 brp-inc 1
          clock 30000000

root@ATK-IMX6U:~# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
mx6s_capture           14876  0
```